# Stopping a barcode scanner refreshing page

Tags: forms, submit, barcode

I am using a barcode scanner in an HTML form and have a problem with the page refreshing

The scanner's input goes into this form (html 5):

```
<form>
<label for "bar_code">Item</label>
<input
name="bar_code"
id="bar_code" 
onchange = "processBarCode('getitemdetails.php', this.value);"
onfocus="setStyle(this.id);"
autofocus
>
</form>
```

The `processBarCode` is a AJAX function that checks if the barcode is in a mySQL database and if it is adds the item to a `<form>` further down the page, this works perfectly. The problem is that because the bar code scanner adds an enter to the end of the scan when the function returns it triggers a submit thus causing the page to refresh.

I need the added enter for the `onchange` to work automatically but still need to disable the page refresh.

Any ideas gratefully received!!

Answer (score 2):

Change your form element to cancel the submit:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: @bob, you should accept the answer (check box outline in the next to the vote count) if it worked for you.